# cannot load such file -- fox16 (LoadError) error on eclipse of fedora

Tags: fxruby

I installed "eclipse" and want to run "fxruby" on fedora "linux", but it does not work it.
The error says :

> cannot load such file -- fox16 (LoadError)

I installed this file with command

```
gem install fxruby
```

but *fxruby* not exist in gem list.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that there were no errors when you ran `gem install fxruby`?

Comment: hello and thanks for your attention but i already find it and write about in other places but because of nobody cares  i did not renew.